# Is there any minimum requirements in a database that already exists to be fully adapted to Laravel 5.6?

Tags: database, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a system that is already working in production and I want to migrate to laravel. I am going to use 5.6 version.

So I have already a database and I do not want to redesign it again.

I know that I could use reliese/Laravel for example in order to create Eloquent models from the database that is already in use.

The point is that the database is not well written, some relationship that should have a foreign key constraint - I don't have. In general I would say that the database do not fit the minimum normalization requirements. But this is what is working now and redesign the database is out of question.

Said that, I would like to know what are the minimum requirements to have Eloquent fully working with this database or this is not the case?

Comment: You should be defining relationships between models in order for eloquent to work. HasMany ManyToMany relationship within the model. And the migration file itself should reflect this relationship

Comment: When we first create the migration and later the database all these relationship are created and translated to the models. So your suggestion  is that I should create the models and then define the relations for all table? I will not use migration because I don't want to create the database again.

Answer (score 0):

a few things to consider:

1. the table names: when creating your models you can set the table name property through `protected $table = 'yourTableName'`
2. the Primary Key Fields: `if the database has an id field in every table you are good if they dont you will need to explicitly setup the primary key through declaring a`protected $primaryKey = 'yourPrimaryID'`
3. the timestamps `created_at` and `updated_at` you can disable the timestamping through `protected $timestamps = false`
4. consider aligning the time-format with carbon.
5. relationships can still work however you have to explicitly define them.

that being said those are what i think will be your primary concerns, i have been working on an inherited database with no (laravel-standards) and it works just fine. if you do not want to completely re-write your database you can easily make `views` and i mean database views not blade views. those are a great way to shape your database without having to migrate data.
good luck